# OCIError on 'require'; permissions issue?

Tags: ruby, oracle, solaris, oci8

I've just recently started learning/using Ruby at work.  I've got a super-simple test script that just connects to our Oracle 10g database, runs a select, and 'puts' the results to the screen.  This is on a Solaris 10 server.  If I run the script as the 'apps' user (the system user that runs our automated scripts), the script runs fines.  If I run it as myself, it throws an error:

```
oci8lib.c:98:in oci8lib.so: OCI Library Initialization Error (OCIError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/oci8.rb:25
    from ./dbTest.rb:3:in `require'
    from ./dbTest.rb:3
```

My env vars match the 'apps' user's.  I'm assuming this is a permissions issue on some file/directory or other but I don't know where to start looking.  Line 25 in the oci8.rb file is a "require 'oci8lib_18'" directive.  I have read and execute permissions on the oci8lib_18.so file and the dirs leading to it, but I don't know which dirs *it* needs to access.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what files/dirs I should check the permissions on?  Or any other thoughts on what the issue may be?

**UPDATE** I've been emailing with the guy that supports OCI8 and it turns out that several of the Oracle directories have permissions that prevent my login from accessing needed info.  A simple test was to try to run sqlplus, which also failed.

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been emailing with the guy that supports OCI8 and it turns out that several of the Oracle directories have permissions that prevent my login from accessing needed info. A simple test was to try to run sqlplus, which also failed.

Answer (score 2):

A priori I have no idea.  Do other ruby apps run using OCI?  Normally libraries and the subsidiary libraries are all installed rwx-r-xr-x. You should never see permissions errors on correctly installed libraries. So I'm making a wild guess you are missing something in your environment, probably like an entry in LD_LIBRARY_PATH

ldd opens shared libraries pretty much the same way your run time image does.

see if this works first:

```
cd /path/to/library   # where oci8lib.so lives.  
ldd oci8lib.so
```

This should display all of the externally linked libraries, with no errors.
If ldd works, check your LD_LIBRARY_PATH to be sure the path you are now in is declared there. If it does not work, you have some kind of installation issue, like missing libraries, or non-standard paths to libraries.

Get back to us here with your results.

Comment: I've updated my question.  Thanks for the tip on 'ldd'; I've never used that before.