# Ruby - OCI Library Initialization Error

Tags: ruby, oracle, oci8

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why I might be getting the error below?

This is on a windows 10 machine with both 32 and 64 bit oracle 12c clients installed (not the instant client).

I have looked at this post, but I am not sure if it is similar or not as they were using linux. [OCI error on require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101680/ocierror-on-require-permissions-issue)

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'oci8'
OCIError: OCI Library Initialization Error - C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Client\12c\12.1.0.2.0x86_1\Client\bin\OCI.DLL
    from oci8lib.c:156:in oci8lib_220.so
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.2-x86-mingw32/lib/oci8.rb:72:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from C:/Ruby22/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my problem was that the ORACLE_HOME was set to the 64 bit home directory.  I removed both the 32 and 64 bit clients then did a fresh install of the 32 bit.  Seems to work now.